# [SoftLayer][API][Check if a VS was migrated to other Xen Host]

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are currently afeted by SL migration plan:  [IBM Bluemix Event] ID:37820643 - Planned Maintenance - VSI Migrations

I need to know using python API if a server will be migrated and also if it was migrated successful.

I checked the api and I used this mask:

```
object_mask = 'pendingMigrationFlag,lastTransaction[transactionGroup]'
```

To check if the server will be migrated I was able to use: vs['pendingMigrationFlag'] and it worked ok.

But to check if a server was migrated in a period of time, I tried to use:

```
 if 'Cloud Migrate' in vs['lastTransaction']['transactionGroup']['name']:
     migrated = True
     transaction_stop = elem['lastTransaction']['modifyDate']
```

but this is seems to not be accurate. (I found servers with `pendingMigrationFlag = False` and `{migrated = True, transaction_stop = 2016..}`

Is there any other option to check if a server was migrated in a the last month?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is possible via API, the main problem is that once the server has been migrated and any other transaction runs in the server you will lose the migration transaction, so even the server has benn migrated in the month you will not be able to know that at least you can see the transaction history, but that is not accesible via API for the customers.

Regarding to your issue you could add a filter to get only the last transaction which has been executed in the last month likely your server has been migrated months ago.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Can the Xen version of the host be extracted via API? It could be a viable solution to find out if a host was migrated or not(Xen version 7 in this case can indicate that the server was migrated). There were cases when pendingMigrationFlag was True but the virtual server wasn't migrated due to possible some internal errors (we couldn't see them in the transaction logs) or maybe some servers need 2-3 migrations to be upgraded to the last version.